# Como funciona concorrência em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, concorrência

Estou com um possível problema em javascript.

O problema é que um array pode ter acesso concorrente pois o seguinte script abaixo pode ser chamada no mesmo momento varias vezes pois utilizo websockets.

```
for (let index in list) { // list é o array compartilhado
    if (list[index].id == id) {
        list.splice(index, 1);
    } 
}
```

Em outras linguagens, como java, c etc, pode acontecer de ocorrer a remoção do item errado na lista ou até tentar remover um item que já nem existe mais na lista, mas em javascript é possível? se não ,por que? se sim, existe alguma forma de tratá-lo com nas outras linguagens, algo semelhante à mutex ou semaforo?

Comment: "Não existe concorrência" até que você a escreva a sua propria lógica para administrar isto, mesmo em Java, o  websocket só roda como um processo a parte, da forma que ele receber é como ele vai trabalhar e se não for tratado vai quebrar, seja em Java, JavaScript, Python, C++... Obviamente a tal lista é disponível a todos, o comando que chegar primeiro é o que será executado primeiro, se executar o mesmo comando para um index inexistente na tal lista provavelmente algo vai falhar.

Comment: O servidor envia vários dados para o cliente, o cliente recebe os dados e executa o script, como não existe concorrência?

Comment: Não foi bem o que eu quis dizer, comi algumas palavras, no sentido não existe controle sobre a concorrencia, em Java geralmente tem APIs que facilitam isso, identificando os "clientes" e afins, inclusive eu criei um servidor HTTP em Java com concorrência (controle sobre isto) e fila.

Comment: Complementando o que o @GuilhermeNascimento explicou, em JavaScript não vai ocorrer nenhuma mudança externa nesse `list` quer por ajax ou outra função enquanto esse `for` correr. O JavaScript só corre um processo de cada vez e mesmo o que é "paralelo" não corre em paralelo, tudo é sequencial.

Comment: Muito obrigado! ficou bem esclarecido. Grato aos 2

Answer (score -1):

Em Javascript não existe concorrência, uma única Thread executa o código, dividindo o código em duas partes (pode-se dizer que uma é prioritária e outra menos prioritária). Mas mesmo dividindo em dois, os códigos nunca são executados em paralelo, o que impede os problemas que ocorrem em Java onde várias Threads podem chamar a mesma função ou usar a mesma variável ao mesmo tempo.
A única forma de conseguir paralelismo no Javascript é usando [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), e mesmo assim um worker não consegue acessar as funções e variáveis de outro, ele só se comunica por evento e nunca diretamente.

O Java e linguagens similares te dão uma ferramenta poderosa ao trabalhar com Threads, porém isto tem um alto custo de desenvolvimento pelo perigo que é imposto ao código. É um trade-off, o javascript não tem esse poder mas não sofre dos problemas de processamento concorrente.